Возможны ли в данном случае взаимоблокировки потоков?
Если я не ставлю lock на получение, при этом у меня есть lock на изменение значения, в данном случае возможна взаимоблокировка или я ошибаюсь?
Всегда ли нужно ставить lock как на получение, так и на изменение в ситуации с многопоточностью?
public class MyClass
{
    private object _lock = new object();

    private string _property;

    public string Property
    {
        get
        {
            // Получение без блокировки
            return _property;
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                // Изменение с блокировкой
                _property = value;
            }
        }
    }
}


Присвоение ссылочного типа, коим является string, атомарно. Поэтому в данном случае lock вообще не нужен.

@AlexanderPetrov не совсем понял, а если у меня например используется IEnumerable?

а если у меня например - начинается!.. Покажите конкретный код. Чтобы было о чём говорить.

private IEnumerable<string> _property; - это всего лишь указатель. И в сеттере присвоение _property = value; выполняется атомарно. Лок не нужен.

@AlexanderPetrov спасибо, вроде бы стало немного понятнее (для атомарных операций не существует промежуточного состояния между началом и концом). Подобные присваивания атомарны для всех типов, правильно?
Получается lock был бы нужен если бы я пытался, например, изменять значения самой коллекции из нескольких потоков, верно?

Для потокобезопасного измененения коллекций существуют потокобезопасные коллекции.
Но допустим речь не об этом, а об одном единственном свойстве. Как сказали в комментариях, присвоение ссылочного типа атомарно, а тип string неизменяемый, поэтому здесь lock не нужен в принципе.
Но представим что операция изменения свойства не является потокобезопасной, тогда здесь ошибка, вы не можете добиться потокобезопасности поместив в lock только сеттер, так как если запись не является потокобезопасной, то возможно, что произойдёт небезопасное чтение посередине записи.
Поэтому геттер тоже должен быть под локом.
public string Property
{
    get
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            // небезопасное чтение
        }
    }
    set
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            // небезопасная запись
        }
    }
}

Вы правильно подозреваете, что когда изменение свойства не происходит, то читать можно многопоточно не блокируя потоки между собой. Для этого существует шаблон проектирования Reader-Writer-Lock. Он говорит о том, что пока записи нет, любое количество потоков может читать данные, а когда требуется запись, нужно прекратить все чтения и писать только одним потом одновременно.
private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock = new();

public string Property
{
    get
    {
        _lock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            // небезопасное чтение
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }
    set
    {
        _lock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            // небезопасная запись
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}

В этом случае когда нет записи, блокировок при чтении вообще не будет. Само собой, что если есть гарантия, что операция чтения/записи никогда не выбросит исключение, то оборачивать её в try-finally не требуется.

Спасибо огромное за пример Reader-Writer-Lock. Просто мне нужно заменять коллекцию сразу целиком и я не смотрел в их сторону. Если честно, осталось не совсем понятным для каких типов данных всё-таки lock необходим, я думал что это будет как раз IEnumerable но как выяснилось нет. На сколько я понял любое присвоение является атомарным?

@WebFR IEnumerable<T> это не коллекция, это перечисление, оно не умеет ничего присваивать. Потокобезопасность каждого элемента коллекции к самой коллекции никак не относится и может рассматриваться отдельно от неё.

Т.е. если я буду делать присвоения коллекции из разных потоков, понятное дело что получится бред, у меня такой ситуации нет. Мне было только важно что в момент присвоения не будет проблем со считыванием в других потоках, а раз это все атомарно и промежуточного состояния нет, все должно быть ок.

@WebFR я не понимаю, о чём речь. Если речь про коллекции, то первая строчка ответа выше - почитайте её.

Ок, можно пожалуйста на этом же примере показать условие, когда lock будет в нем действительно необходим? Для необходимости использования lock нужен какой-то другой тип данных для которого это требуется или дополнительное условие?

@WebFR ну например при изменении свойства нужно учитывать старое значение. _property = _property + value; - эта операция уже не будет атомарной. Либо присваивать несколько переменных и т.д. Сеттер это просто метод, в нём какой угодно код можно писать.

Ок, спасибо, не сразу понял про чтение по середине записи, но сейчас дошло, что мы можем что-то изменять например в цикле а считается частично. Огромное спасибо, все моменты для себя разъяснил, и за Reader-Writer-Lock ещё раз спасибо.
